# Mongodb custom _id and time information

Tags: node.js, mongodb

The mongodb collection has docs whose **_id's** are custom formed and does not contain the time information. Now i need to sort the query based on insert time. Does the mongodb keeps any other reference of the time at which the docs are inserted.

Comment: Do you have a sample document with some data?

Comment: doc : {_id: "hello_world1", data : "infooo1"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mondodb _id object contains time information.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/

If you are storing custom value to the **_id**, Then you need to have some other field like **created_at = timestamp**
So that you can sort by created_at.

**Example** store your doc like 
doc :

```
{_id: "hello_world1", data : "infooo1", created_at:"1430851180"}
```

There are no other reference that contain time information. You need to have custom field for storing time.

**Note-** Its better to don't use custom value for _id.